# How to create and manage a 2D array-like List object in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I need a 2D array which is expandable in all directions and strictly tracks overall positioning of each element, but is most efficient at read.

The use case I face is as follows:
I am colliding and mashing 2D tectonic plates into one another. When they collide, they can shrink, grow, or neither. Every iteration, all elements are likely to be accessed, so read time is very important. They must be able to grow/shrink on all sides as well, and can contain holes and convex structures.

Memory is not a huge issue, but I'd like to save it where I can. My main concern is speed, as the old proof of concept this is loosely based on written in C++ takes 15 minutes to run, and I am adding substantially to the original concept.

I initially thought of using a dictionary with coordinates, but this poses the issue of read times; dictionaries are slow when something they do not have a key for is requested, and this will happen often.

I'm considering using a `List<List<MyCLass>>` structure now, using null class objects for empty locations.

Another idea I had was to use an algebraic array (y * stride + x), but would rather avoid the complications thereof, and it would be both hard to build and maintain.

So, essentially, what is the best way to have a very large 2D data set which is constantly accessed and frequently modified in C#?

EDIT:
As requested;
The arrays will likely be between 50x50 and 1000x1000 each, and there will be 10-30 at any given time. the overall 'world' will be 512x512 to 4096x4096 in size (set at start of simulation), with approximately 20% overlap max (excluding edge cases). However, up to 50% of each 2D plate will be empty space in a Cartesian system, so with a uniform size this would mean the actual size of arrays would be double that, so at most, approximately 20,132,659 non-null array elements, and a little less than that in null elements total in the simulation.

I'm OK with this program taking up to several hours to complete a sim, but I worry that it will take days. That's why I am trying to come up with optimal ways to handle these data sets.

Comment: "dictionaries are slow when something they do not have a key for is requested"... are they? I would have thought that mainly this would cause a lookup on an empty bucket. Not too slow.

Comment: Generic List<List> will work for you?

Comment: are you iterating through each item sequentially?  Or will reads be or randomly indexed from a given key?

Comment: Can you post what your data looks like and how your reading it?

Comment: Also post  the number of elements you expect to store in the collection.

Comment: Try either a `List<T>` with algebraic indexing (which I have used many times) or a jagged list `List<List<T>>`.

Comment: An after-thought, what if I was to set up the Array or List to only change it's size every X iterations, growing/shrinking it to have enough padding for the next X iterations assuming max growth; no more or less. Thus while it will use something like 20-30% more memory, it would only evaluate 50-5% of the time.

Comment: I meant `List<List<T>>`, but forgot about the markdown.

Comment: @spender, dictionary lookups will iterate over all possible items in the dictionary when you request something that isnt there.

Comment: @NSjonas
Both. Random access for specific operations (about half of the accesses total) and sequential otherwise. (Yes, this thing is insane)

Comment: @Dreadicon :  I'd love to see the reference that led you to conclude that a lookup on a dictionary (which is in reality a hashtable) for a non-existent key is O(n). Unless I'm mistaken it's O(1). Prove me wrong.

Comment: @Dreadicon : If the hashtable is heavily loaded (eg entries/buckets is high) then lookups will be costly. You could acheive this with a GetHashCode that has very poor distribution but that would be a coding mistake. Otherwise, my belief is that you are wrong.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @spender - This is where I got my performance metrics for arrays vs dictionaries: [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-dictionary-test)

I havent been able to locate where I got my notion that looking up an element which does not exist is O(n), but finding the arbitrary mapping must have overhead compared to a direct index from everything I know.

Based on the fact that each data set (in my case) will be at minimum 1000 elements, and at max somewhere around 4,000,000, I just don't see how a dictionary/hashtable for such a large set could compare to direct indexes.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on having an expandable 2D array (matrix) then consider the following:

```
public class Matrix<T> : Collection<T>
{
    int row_count, col_count;
    List<T> _list; //reference to inner list
    T[] _items; //reference to inner array within inner list

    public Matrix(int row_count, int col_count)
        : this(row_count, col_count, new T[row_count*col_count])
    {
        if(row_count==0||col_count==0)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    Matrix(int row_count, int col_count, T[] values)
        : base(new List<T>(values))
    {
        // internal data arranged in 1D array, by rows.
        this._list=base.Items as List<T>;
        this.row_count=row_count;
        this.col_count=col_count;
        LinkInnerArray();
    }

    private void LinkInnerArray()
    {
        this._items=typeof(List<T>).GetField("_items",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
            |System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(base.Items) as T[];
    }

    public int RowCount { get { return row_count; } }
    public int ColCount { get { return col_count; } }
    public T[] Elements { get { return _list.ToArray(); } }

    public T this[int row, int col]
    {
        get { return base[col_count*row+col]; }
        set { base[col_count*row+col]=value; }
    }

    public T[] GetRow(int row)
    {
        if(row<0||row>=row_count) new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        T[] result=new T[col_count];
        lock(_items)
        {
            // fast array copy
            Array.Copy(_items, col_count*row, result, 0, result.Length);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public T[] GetColumn(int column)
    {
        if(column<0||column>=col_count) new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        T[] result=new T[row_count];
        lock(_items)
        {
            // No shortcut exists, only if C# was more like FORTRAN
            for(int i=0; i<row_count; i++)
            {
                result[i]=base[col_count*i+column];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public void SetRow(int row, params T[] values)
    {
        if(values==null||values.Length==0) return;
        if(row<0||row>=row_count) new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        // fast array copy
        lock(_items)
        {
            Array.Copy(values, 0, _items, col_count*row, values.Length);
        }
    }
    public void SetColumn(int column, params T[] values)
    {
        if(values==null||values.Length==0) return;
        if(column<0||column>=col_count) new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        lock(_items)
        {
            // No shortcut exists, only if C# was more like FORTRAN
            for(int i=0; i<values.Length; i++)
            {
                base[col_count*i+column]=values[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddRow(params T[] new_row)
    {
        lock(_list)
        {
            // add array to last row
            T[] row=new T[col_count];
            Array.Copy(new_row, 0, row, 0, new_row.Length);
            _list.AddRange(row);
            LinkInnerArray();
            this.row_count++;
        }
    }

    public void AddColumn(params T[] new_column)
    {
        lock(_list)
        {
            // go add an item on end of each row
            for(int i=row_count-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                T item=i<new_column.Length?new_column[i]:default(T);
                _list.Insert(col_count*i+row_count-1, item);
            }
            LinkInnerArray();
            this.col_count++;
        }
    }

    public Matrix<R> Transform<R>(Func<T, R> operation)
    {
        R[] values=new R[row_count*col_count];
        for(int i=0; i<values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i]=operation(base[i]);
        }
        return new Matrix<R>(row_count, col_count, values);
    }

    public Matrix<R> Combine<R>(Matrix<T> other, Func<T, T, R> operation)
    {
        R[] values=new R[row_count*col_count];
        for(int i=0; i<values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i]=operation(base[i], other[i]);
        }
        return new Matrix<R>(row_count, col_count, values);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N=4;
        var A=new Matrix<int>(N, N);
        // initialize diagonal
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            A[i, i]=1;
        }

        // A = 
        // | 1  0  0  0 |
        // | 0  1  0  0 |
        // | 0  0  1  0 |
        // | 0  0  0  1 |

        A.AddRow(5, 4, 3, 2);
        A.AddColumn(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        // A = 
        // | 1  0  0  0  1 |
        // | 0  1  0  0  2 |
        // | 0  0  1  0  3 |
        // | 0  0  0  1  4 |
        // | 5  4  3  2  5 |

        var B=A.Transform(delegate(int x) { return 5-x; });
        // B = 
        // | 4  5  5  5  4 |
        // | 5  4  5  5  3 |
        // | 5  5  4  5  2 |
        // | 5  5  5  4  1 |
        // | 0  1  2  3  0 |

        var C=A.Combine(B, delegate(int x, int y) { return y-x; });
        // C = 
        // | 3  5  5  5  3 |
        // | 5  3  5  5  1 |
        // | 5  5  3  5 -1 |
        // | 5  5  5  3 -3 |
        // |-5 -3 -1  1 -5 |
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have built it with an inner array directly, and use the `Array.Resize()` function.

Comment: Wow, that's quite the class, but also exceptionally useful! I'll leave this open for another couple days, and see if I can't run some metrics using this method, but this looks like what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are reading your Collections.

For example, if you are looping through each element then a List will always be faster than a dictionary.

```
List<List<Item>> collection = new List<List<Items>>();
//add items
for(List l : collection){
 for(Item i : l){
   //do something with item
 }
}
```

If you're looking up indexes, based on a "key" value, then the dictionary will always be faster (constant vs linear).

```
Dictionary<String,List<Item>> collection = new Dictionary<String,List<Items>>();
//add items
List<String> keysWeNeedToWorkOn = new List<String>();
//add keys we care about
for(String key : keysWeNeedToWorkOn){
   for(Item i : collection.get(key)){
     // do something with this item
  }
}
```

This [Big O Cheat sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) might be helpful for you to decide exactly what you need.

Comment: oh, that cheat sheet IS really useful! will have to bookmark/save that one! But I was curious, if I was looking up arrayObject[x,y], wouldnt that be faster than dictObject[xyvalue]? I will always be able to look up items based on their coordinates, but it will be a mix of iterating over every item in the set and accessing specific ones directly using a known position. Dict saves memory, but each time you ask for an item which does not exist, it will iterate over all items in the list iirc.

Comment: If you try to access a item not in the dictionary, it won't iterate over the entire array.  Map/Dictionarys work by creating a HASHING function to apply to the key values.  When you add an item, it hashes the key and stores it in that memory location. To perform a lookup, the dictionary simply Hashes the key and returns the item at that memory location. More than 1 key can resolve to the same location but a good Hashing algorithm prevents this. @spender already mentioned this above.  Lookups on a MAP/Dictionary will always be constant, regardless if the key exists or not.

Comment: I understand now. After further educating myself on the hashtable process, I see how this works now. Sorry for my faulty assumptions on the matter. Assuming C#'s hashing produces few collisions, the lookup time IS more or less linear, and as you said doesnt change for existant/nonexistant items. however, there is still a fixed overhead attatched to the hash lookup compared with direct memory access. This is evidenced in this article: http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-dictionary-test

Comment: Despite the above, your advice very much helped point me in the right direction! Thankyou!

Comment: @Dreadicon you know whats better than "thank you"?  Making that little checkmark next to my answer turn green ;)

Comment: And in response to your previous comment.  There is definitely overhead in a dictionary lookup, and it is definitely always slower than INDEXING (not the same as a lookup) into an array, but the point is that dictionary lookups scale with CONSTANT time O(1).  Meaning if you double your array, your lookup time will stay the same (more or less).  On the other hand, the more elements you add to a Array, the longer it takes to lookup/search for them O(n).